# Is it possible to compare different fields in jsonb

Tags: sql, json, postgresql-9.5

Table with column type **jsonb**.

Here json

```
"weight": {
    "qty": 1112,
    "unit": {
      "name": "gram"
    }
  },
  "options": [
    {
      "name": "genus_species",
      "value": {
        "name": "cucumber"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "weight",
      "value": {
        "name": "600g"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "method",
      "value": {
        "name": "salt"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "tm",
      "value": {
        "name": "chudova-marka"
      }
    }
  ]
```

In this example "**weight.qty**" with value "**1112**" not equal with "**value.name.600g**". So this record **will be return**.

P.S. I convert "**qty**" to string and add suffix "**g**" to can compare as strings.

So here query without compare

```
SELECT 
concat(product.data->'weight'->>'qty', 'g') AS weight,
product.data #>>'{options,0,value,name}' as n1,
product.data #>>'{options,1,value,name}' as n2,
product.data #>>'{options,2,value,name}' as n3,
product.data #>>'{options,3,value,name}' as n4
FROM product
```

I need to show records where "**weight.qty**" not equals with any  "**options.value.name**".
Is it possible?

Comment: Don't you want to limit the comparison to options with `name = weight`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I need to compare only with options.weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the array elements:

```
select p.*
from product p
where not exists (select * 
                  from jsonb_array_elements(p.data -> 'options') as x(option)
                  where x.option ->> 'name' = 'weight' 
                    and x.option -> 'value' ->> 'name' = concat(p.data->'weight'->>'qty', 'g'))
```